# When does a MWAA environment update it's requirements, and is it an automatic or manual process?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

Pretty much title.
Supose I edit the `requirements.txt` file to add a new package, or to change package versions. When will the environment apply these changes, and what manual steps do I have to take (if any) to make that happen?
The [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/working-dags-dependencies.html#working-dags-dependencies-mwaaconsole-version) on the procedure states that one must simply go through the 'Edit' settings, but in the case I didn't even change the filename is it necessary?

Answer (score 3):

In the MWAA settings, you will change the version of requirements.txt (the name of the file will remain the same). You choose the latest version of the file and save it. As soon as you save it, the MWAA instance will restart automatically to update and install the packages mentioned in the "requirements.txt" file.